# Is it possible to use matplotlib and pylab to create filled line graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if it is possible to create a filled line graph, like below, using matplotlib?

I have matplotlib 0.91.2 and pylab installed.

[image]
http://test1.xsports.co.nz/media/Forecast.png

Answer (score 2):

[This example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html) in the matplotlib gallery looks like it will do what you want - you just have to fill between the graph and the x-axis.

Alternatively, you could use a bar graph with many single pixel bars (or whatever resolution you wanted).

HTH

Comment: He specifically needs to use fill_between at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between